# Apache not starting with SSL virtualhost

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, https

MY server (Apache/Ubuntu) runs fine with plain http, but won't start when I try to add a https certificate and configuration.

```
sudo service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error 
code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This gives:

```
> sudo journalctl | tail
Jun 13 10:56:28 apache2[11045]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jun 13 10:56:28 apache2[11045]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 13 10:56:28 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 13 10:56:28 sudo[11015]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 13 10:56:28 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 13 10:56:28 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 13 10:56:28 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And:

```
> systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-06-13 10:56:28 UTC; 1min 48s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10676 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8285 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11045 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

My 000-default.conf look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myserver.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName myserver.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/crt/domain.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/crt/domain.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/html/crt/domain.cacert
</VirtualHost>
```

At least for the time being, I gave everything in the certificate folder 770 permissions for the `www-data` user and group. Just to eliminate a permissions issue. It looks like the `SSLEngine on` statement is what triggers the error.

There is no further info in the Apache error log (probably because it doesn't start in the first place.

Comment: `apache2ctl configtest` would tell you what is wrong in your configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Got a few steps further. Biggest problem was a lack of debugging info, but the following command is helpful:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

I gives a syntax error with the line `SSLEngine`. Apparently Ubuntu needs to run the following command to enable ssl:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Now the apache server should start normally.